# ISCHANGED(ISPICKVAL() formula

Tags: formula

I have a process builder in place for when an opp is in Discovery stage and Type is not Rollover to send an alert and if it is a rollover in discovery to send a different alert. Every time the opp is saved while in Discovery stage, it is sending out the alert. I need the alert to only go out when it is first changed to discovery. I am trying to use the below formula, but I am getting syntax errors.

```
AND (
ISCHANGED(ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName)),
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName = "Discovery"),
ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type<> "Rollover (Existing Client)"),
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a formula; you can use the normal "conditions is met" mode. Set it to Stage equals Discovery and Type not equal to Rollover (Existing Client). Then, in the **Advanced** section (near the bottom, collapsed by default), check the "Yes" box. This will cause the rule to trigger only when the condition is initially met.

---

As for your formula, ISCHANGED works for all fields, so you don't need to use ISPICKVAL:

```
AND(
  ISCHANGED([Opportunity].StageName),
  ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].StageName = "Discovery"), 
  ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type<> "Rollover (Existing Client)")
)
```